# Magento Extensions: Adding a custom block to the product view

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I'm having an issue adding a custom PHP block to the product view in Magento. **The block simply won't display on the product page**.

This is part of my first Magento extension. Hoping you can help me.

My approach is based on the tutorial at the following link:
https://gist.github.com/grafikchaos/11148771

Note that I am not tied to the process in this tutorial - I am open to any suggestions / adjustments to this approach.

My files created/adjusted are as follows:

**/app/etc/modules/Whirlwindecom_Personalizer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- located at: app/etc/modules/Whirlwindecom_Personalizer.xml -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Whirlwindecom_Personalizer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Whirlwindecom_Personalizer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Whirlwindecom/Personalizer/etc/config.xml**

Note this file contains additional nodes to support other parts of this extension that are working and are not related to this issue

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Whirlwindecom_Personalizer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Whirlwindecom_Personalizer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <whirlwindecom_personalizer>
                <class>Whirlwindecom_Personalizer_Block</class>
            </whirlwindecom_personalizer>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <whirlwindecom_personalizer>
                <class>Whirlwindecom_Personalizer_Model</class>
            </whirlwindecom_personalizer>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <whirlwindecom_personalizer>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Whirlwindecom_Personalizer</module>
                    <frontName>personalizer</frontName>
                </args>
            </whirlwindecom_personalizer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <whirlwindecom_personalizer module="Whirlwindecom_Personalizer">
                    <file>whirlwindecom_personalizer.xml</file>
                </whirlwindecom_personalizer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <whirlwindecom_personalizer>
                    <file>whirlwindecom_personalizer.xml</file>
                </whirlwindecom_personalizer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Whirlwindecom_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Whirlwindecom_Personalizer_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                    </Whirlwindecom_save_product_data>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/whirlwindecom_personalizer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="whirlwind_personalizer">
            <block type="core/template" name="whirlwind_personalizer_block" template="whirlwindecom/personalizer/personalize.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

**/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

Added the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('whirlwind_personalizer_block'); ?>
```

Before:

```
<div class="product-shop">
```

**/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/whirlwindecom/personalizer/personalize.phtml**

```
<?php
// let's output a message to verify this script is being included and displayed
echo "Personalizer Success!";
?>
```

One final note. In an attempt to debug my work and trace the cause of the problem, I temporarilly added the following code to the view.phtml script at the same place as my getChildHtml line:

```
var_dump(array_keys($this->getLayout()->getAllBlocks()));
```

It outputted the following, which verifies that Magento sees the block?:

```
array(100) {
    ...
    [95]=> string(28) "whirlwind_personalizer_block"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code of file

**/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/whirlwindecom_personalizer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="whirlwind_personalizer_block" template="whirlwindecom/personalizer/personalize.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: TY Preshant - you are a life saver!!